# Where does the thumb/handle/button in TrackBar come from?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, aero, trackbar

When I have a Forms.TrackBar (aka "Slider") in a Window that is shown with a "Windows Classic" desktop, the old gray pointy thumbs are rendered.
When I start the same application with Aero activated, it renders the thumb in the selected Aero style.

For the case where VisualStyles are enabled (Aero), there is
TrackBarRenderer.DrawRightPointingThumb
for example, which renders the thumb accoring to the new styles engine.

Without VisualStyles, one can use ControlPaint methods to draw certain gui elements, but no the thumb for a slider.

My questions now are: Does anyone know where the classic slider thumb is located? Is it a Bitmap or does it get painted in some OnPaint code? Why is there no method to paint it with ControlPaint?

Maybe there is something special about this piece of grafix, but I can't see why.

Comment: It belongs to a general category of XyzRenderer classes.  Like ComboBox, ProgressBar, ScrollBar, Tab, TextBox.  And the ones that actually get used by the framework; Button, Checkbox, GroupBox, RadioButton.  Only the latter have a classic fallback, no fallback for the ones it doesn't use.   Why it was done this way is hard to guess, maybe they had bigger plans for the FlatStyle property and it just didn't get done in time.  TrackBar is a native Windows control, not a .NET control, stored in comctl32.dll and written in C++.  Almost surely just paint code.  That's not going to help you.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant and thanks for the comment. That actually was exactly what I coudln't figure out, esp. the fact there are really different apporaches to different native widgets and they didn't all get the same treatment over the years. Also I couldn't find the reference to comctl32.dll.
This cleared things up for me quite a bit.
Why didn't you post it as an answer? It totally is (at least to me, and I am pretty sure I am not the only person on the planet wondering about these inconsistencies ;-) )